# remote event receiver not firing when published

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, azure, remote-event-receiver

I followed all the steps of this [blog](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/03/13/remote-event-receiver-rer-for-host-web-using-sharepoint-provider-hosted-app-in-office-365sharepoint-online-environment/) and successfully deployed the web app and sharepoint addin but now the remote event receiver doesnt get triggered when adding an item to the list.

Comment: That article doesn't say anything about remote event receivers.

Comment: @DerekGusoff sorry i updated the links